# S3 SELECT on Parquet file doesn't return any record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-s3-select

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

resp = s3.select_object_content(

    Bucket='s3-nb-demo',
    Key='sample_data.parquet',
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="SELECT * FROM s3object s where s.\"Name\" = 'NB'",
    InputSerialization = {'Parquet': {}},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
)

for event in resp['Payload']:

    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        statsDetails = event['Stats']['Details']
        print("Stats details bytesScanned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesScanned'])
        print("Stats details bytesProcessed: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesProcessed'])
        print("Stats details bytesReturned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesReturned'])
```

The code doesn't return any rows. I have verified the data file and query using Athena and it returns multiple rows. The `resp['Payload']` object doesn't have an attribute called `Records`. I have seen lots of examples using CSV file, but no post on Parquet file.

Comment: Does the query work if you try it in the Amazon S3 management console?

Comment: I am not sure if s3 select have console access. However, I tried in Athena and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: In the S3 management console, click into an object and then click the **Select from** tab.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right place at the console. I see the preview but having hard time making the query working. I think the issue was with the Parquet file. I tried with a different file and it worked.

Comment: Hi John,

I have a follow-up question related to previous question.

On the console if I run:

select * from s3object where line_item_usage_account_id = '123456789321' limit 200000

I get all the results back. However, if I run the following SQL:

select * from s3object where line_item_usage_account_id = '123456789321'

It throws error "Operation Incomplete". Any suggestions ?

Comment: It's just the `LIMIT` that's different? Normally, people would use S3 Select to extract specific rows of data using a `WHERE` statement. I would not recommend S3 Select for retrieving ALL rows, since for that you could simply download the original file.

Comment: I am trying to get all the columns using 'select *'. I will have a where clause slice the data. line_item_usage_account_id = '123456789321' is my where clause.

Comment: So, if you add the WHERE clause, does the `select_object_content()` call work? If adding the `LIMIT` makes it work, then I guess just keep adding the limit, with a number higher than you need.